# Are link-only answers acceptable here?

Tags: discussion, answers

Should we accept answers which only provide third-party link and the author claims it to contain the answers?

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not acceptable on this site or any SE site. They should be:

- downvoted
- flagged as *it is not an answer*
- elected for *recommend delete* or *delete*, when presented in the review queue
- commented with `While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.` if one doesn't exists. This template is however provide by the system to be automatically inserted if visit through the review queue.

Why?

- answer which contain link to the answer, if faced with [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) are rendered useless
- [visit this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) (would y'all make an exception on this ? <sup><sub>:P</sub></sup>)